# Is it ok to say "basis of a lattice"?

Tags: terminology, integer-lattices

Consider a lattice $\Lambda \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$. To fix such an isomorphism one should fix elements $v_1, \dots, v_n \in \Lambda$ such that the whole of $\Lambda$ is generated by these vectors.

**Question** How should a call such a set of generators of a lattice? Is the word "basis" good?

*Remark.* Sorry if I am too pedagogical. But let me point out, that if you embed $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then set $v_1, \dots, v_n$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But not any basis $w_1, \dots, w_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (even if you require $w_i \in \Lambda$) is a basis of $\Lambda$. For instance $(2,0)$, $(0,1)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but not a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the right terminology given that a lattice is a [free $\Bbb Z$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module).

Comment: Note that any given lattice has many different bases, which are related by unimodular transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided that the generating set is *free* (i.e. $e_i\mapsto  v_i$ extends to an isomorphism $\mathbf Z^n\to \Lambda$).

Comment: This is automatic since $\Bbb Z$ has [invariant basis number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number) and the OP assumes $\Lambda \simeq \Bbb Z^n$ in the introduction.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: Does it obviously imply that there is no non-free generating set?

Comment: I overlooked that. There is clearly no non-free generating set with $n$ elements because such a set would be generating $\Bbb R^n$, therefore $\Bbb R$-free and therefore $\Bbb Z$-free. But it's an interesting question to see whether the IBN property by itself is enough (+1 for that question).

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: Yeah, sure, what I had in mind is a larger generating set. Read literally, the question disallows this, but it is not very explicit about that.